# copying files using non-root rsync

Tags: rsync, sudo, root

I have a primary server and a secondary server and I wish to copy files over from the primary to the secondary using rsync. I have mounted the primary disk onto the secondary using NFS and am copying data pertaining to multiple users at the primary server onto the secondary.

Is there any way I can do this without root privileges?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to keep the user permissions for multiple users you need to run it as root.  Even if the files are all readable a regular user account won't be able to set the owner properly.

Comment: Would there be an alternative if I did not want to keep the user permissions?

Comment: If the files are all readable by the user you want to run rsync with, yes.  You may need to use the --fake-super or --no-super arguments to rsync.